# Resizing input-group-addon not resizing

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to make a input form with a visual feedback. If the user inputs a number in the input field, the input field along with the addon turns green and a check mark or a cross mark appears next to the currency text.

My issue is that the glypicon overlaps with the currency text all the time. I have tried nesting the second span into the first one as well as modifying margins, paddings to allow for it but the input-group-addon is not budging. What would be a clean and good way of ensuring that the glyphicon is positioned after the currency text?

```
<div class="col-sm-3 inputGroupContainer">
    <div class="input-group">
        <input type="number" class="form-control" name="price" value=50 data-moneyamount="moneyamount" required />
        <span class="input-group-addon">
            USD
        </span>
        <span class="glyphicon form-control-feedback" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: try [validator.js](http://1000hz.github.io/bootstrap-validator/) , the second sample on their examples is what you are after, I think.

Comment: that is more of a work around i think. Moving the input-group-addon to the left and making the check mark be in the input field.

Comment: also it wouldn't work too well because the input type is a number and then i have the ingrement and decrement arrows on the right of the field. Now the glyphicon shows on top of those.